# What's the most efficient way to pull only the records created since last pull?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, ruby-on-rails-6, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am building a Shopify App, and I want my customer (the store owner) to 'sync' the app with their store data occasionally, specifically for their `Order` data (ignore the fact that I will also have a webhook that pushes this data to my app whenever a new order is created).

Right now, just for crude illustration purposes, I am doing this (which works in dev mode):

```
store_orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all)
store_orders.each do |sorder|
  new_order = Order.find_or_create_by(s_order_id: sorder.id)
  new_order.update(
    currency: sorder.currency,
    ...
  )
```

So, I am pulling all of the orders directly from the `ShopifyAPI`. Ideally, what I want to happen is to only pull the new orders that have been made that have not been synced.

I have two constraints:

- The `Order IDs` produced by the `ShopifyAPI` are not in a sequential order, and can be relatively haphazard
- I can't do a `where` query on the `ShopifyAPI` according to the `updated_at` date, i.e. to only select the records after my last synced date (the `ShopifyAPI` is not allowing this at the moment, I am not sure if this will be fixed in the future).

So that leaves me with two questions:

1. What's another, efficient way, for me to quickly find the records that have not been pulled and only pull those?
2. How do I make sure to only update the records locally that any attribute has been changed or no record exists before? (i.e. I am trying to avoid updating every record that has been pulled).

Comment: Their docs say they do support filtering by timestamp, look for the created_at_min / updated_at_min examples https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order

Comment: If you're having trouble with the Shopify::API gem you can open a ticket on their support or just make the http request yourself and not through the gem maybe? clearly the api supports it no need to look for complex solutions

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you figure the Shopify order ID is "haphazard" and not in "sequential" order? If you study these things, you will find that they are integers and in fact, they are in order in the sense that an order created after another will have a bigger ID.

So the coolest little thing you can do, really quite easy, is to use the Shopify API filter known as "since_id". You get the luxury of pulling only orders that hit Shopify SINCE the last pull, assuming you stored that last pulled ID in the since_id field you keep around, on the shop model you keep.

Try it. It works perfectly. I have been doing that for years. Just update the since_id in your DB once you're done processing a batch of orders, and then next time you want more, filter using your since_id.

Comment: This is perfect. I hadn't realized there is a `since_id` attribute, but that makes sense. I will dig into that some more. Thanks!

Comment: Have you used `since_id` on `AbandonedCheckout` objects? The issue is the REST API returns the `token` when you try to get the `id` for each object, so not quite sure how that works.